# Hardy Ramanujan Question

Tags: equation-solving, programming

I revised the code I asked about earlier, but I am still not getting an output. According to Mathematica it is (mostly) correct syntax. Here is the revised function:

```
Ramanujan_Number[N_] := 
 Module[{taxicablist = {}, int_count = 0, i, j, k, l, m, MAX},
  MAX = N;
  For[i = 1, i < MAX, i++,
    For[j = 1, j < MAX^(1/3), j++,
     For[l = 1, i < MAX^(1/3), i++,
      For[m = 1, j < MAX^(1/3), j++,
       For[k = 1, k^3 < MAX^(1/3), k++,
        If[j^3 + l^3 == k^3 + m^3 && j^3 + l^3 == i, 
          AppendTo[taxicablist, i], Return[0]];
        ]
       ]
      ]
     ]
    ]
   Print[taxicablist];
  ]


Ramanujan_Number[10000]
```

Comment: Use `RamanujanNumber` instead of `Ramanujan_Number`. [Blank (_)](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blank.html) is a built-in object in WL.

Comment: ... btw, so is [N](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/N.html).

Comment: I changed the function to RamanujanNumber. When I was defining the code, I put N_ in the function input since that is standard for Mathematica.

Comment: @TimothyAaronnNorris it might be better to use `n_` instead, or `Nn_`, as [`N`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) is a built-in symbol that calls a function which gives the numerical value of the expression it is applied to. I.e. taking `2` to `2.`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`PowersRepresentations`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowersRepresentations) instead?

```
PowersRepresentations[1729, 2, 3]
```

> {{1, 12}, {9, 10}}

or:

```
Cases[
    Table[PowersRepresentations[n, 2, 3], {n, 10000}],
    p_ /; Length[p]>1
]
```

> {{{1, 12}, {9, 10}}, {{2, 16}, {9, 15}}}